# railsのファイルを作成・rails sに関してのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: エラー表示がわかりません]

とても初歩的なところですが、このようなエラーが出てしまいます。
原因はなんなのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: エラーとなったファイルパスに関して、 /Users/aochuguang, /Users/aochuguang/.rbenv, ... どのディレクトリまでなら aochuguang ユーザーの権限でファイルを作ることが出来るでしょうか。(/Usersには書けないはずなのでスキップでOK) できなかったとしたらそのディレクトリの所有者は?

Comment: 行った手順などを記載すると良い回答が付くと思いますよ。rbenv辺りからの手順があると良いかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。最初なので全く理解しておらず、Udemyで学習しているのですが、講師の方が質問の回答ができない状態なので質問させていただきました。もう一度最初からゆっくりやっていきたいと思います。

Comment: アップデートしたらすることが出来ました。初歩的なことで本当にすみません。コメントしていただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

インストールエラーではないでしょうか？
もう一度インストールするか、アップデートしてみてはいかがでしょう？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます!アップデートしたらできました。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: 上手く行かれたようなので幸いです。